# Get PFObject from query

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, parse-platform, nsarray

I'm building an app that uses Parse as a backend service. I got a column named "Title" and a column named "Author" as well as many other columns. I'm using a specific title to try and get the author corresponding to that PFObject but I don't know how to "convert" the query into an object in which I can extract the Author string.

This is what I've tried, might be completely weird:

```
    // Create an instance of MyManager
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];

// Create a query
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Story"];

// Set the title
[query whereKey:@"Title" equalTo:sharedManager.selectedStory];

// Set selectedAuthor in MyManager
NSArray *result = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[query findObjects]];
for (int i = 0; i < result.count; i++) {
    // NSLog
    PFObject *object;
    object = result;

    NSString *author = [object objectForKey:@"Author"];
    NSLog(author);
}
```

but then Xcode tells me this:

```
-[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

**What am I doing wrong and what is the fastest way to accomplish what I am trying?**

Thanks!
Erik

Comment: `for (PFObject *object in result){NSString *author = [object objectForKey:@"Author"];}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Used  asynchronously method to fetch the result

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if(error)
    {
      //Show the error alert
    }
    else
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {

        PFObject *obj = ((PFObject *)objects[i]);
        NSString *author = [obj objectForKey:@"Author"];
        NSLog(author);
        }
    }
}];
```